# How can I solve my constructor injection code architecture?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

The current code solves the issue I had when trying to use property injection.

**Problem**: Every module must use constructor injection because of a circular reference that occurs when not using constructor injection with my factories and trying to use property injection

**Reason**: A module requires a client and each client must have its own list of instantiated modules.

**What I want**: I want every module that derives from `BaseModule` to be able to not declare a constructor and allow `BaseModule` to have `IIrcClient` injected via a property.

But I'm not sure how to use Ninject to correctly do this without getting a circular reference. Is there a way so that for each client, a new list of modules are injected into that client (where all modules then have an injected reference of the client they belong to).

`.ToFactory()` is an extension method of Ninject which creates a proxy based on an interface that creates an object with a dependency.

```cs
public class BaseClient : IClient
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IModule> modules;

    protected BaseClient(IModuleFactory moduleFactory)
    {
         // each client has its own instances of modules set
         // each module needs a reference to the client
         this.modules = moduleFactory.Create(this);
    }
}

public class BaseModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IIrcClient ircClient;

    // Factory will inject and create 
    protected BaseModule(IIrcClient ircClient)
    {
        this.ircClient = ircClient;
    }
}    

public class Bot
{
    // Injected factory
    public Bot(Context context, IrcClientFactory factory) 
    {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        List<Network> networks = context.Networks.ToList();

        foreach (var network in networks)
        {
            // create new client...but also
            // new client gets injected with module factory
            // module factory then populates modules based on client
            IIrcClient ircClient = this.ircClientFactory.Create();
            ircClient.Connect(network);
            this.clients.Add(ircClient);
        }
    }
} 

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        kernel.Bind<IIrcClient>().To<DefaultIrcClient>();
        kernel.Bind<IIrcClientFactory>().ToFactory();



        kernel.Bind<IModule>().To<DiceModule>().WithPropertyValue("Name", "Dice Module");
        kernel.Bind<IModule>().To<ModuleOne>().WithPropertyValue("Name", "ModuleOne");
        kernel.Bind<IModule>().To<RubyModule>().WithPropertyValue("Name", "Ruby Module");
        kernel.Bind<IModule>().To<AdminModule>().WithPropertyValue("Name", "Admin Module");

        // Module Factory will generate IEnumerable<IModule> 
        kernel.Bind<IModuleFactory>().ToFactory();

        var bot = kernel.Get<Bot>();
        bot.Start();
    }
}
```

A possible fix, but I would have to manaually set the property instead of letting Ninject inject the property:

```
public class BaseClient : IClient
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IModule> modules;

    protected BaseClient(IModuleFactory moduleFactory)
    {
         // let the factory create new modules
         // but dont pass the instance of the client
         this.modules = moduleFactory.Create();

         foreach(var module in modules)
         {
               module.IrcClient = this; // don't want to do this, but I think it would fix it
         }
    }
}
```

This way, I could create tons of modules without needing to always implement the base constructor and pass in the `IClient` dependency:

```
public class ChildModule : BaseModule
{ 
    // client was injected via property

    // override virtual methods as required.
}
```

Comment: Each DI has its pros and cons. Ninject, although very popular, may not be the best option for your situation. Have you tried any others?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, no i have not, though apparently AutoFac is a good alternative.

Comment: I'm not sure... but I do primarily use AutoFac.

Comment: Have you considered perhaps you could make it Laxy:
Either with actual Lazy<T>
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx
Or by instead of depending on being passed the object, ask to be passed a Process<T> ()=> new T()

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what "circular reference" you are getting with your attempted/preferred solution?

Comment: @PatrickMagee if you have found a solution to your problem, you can share it here and earn an easy 100pts :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question isn't crystal-clear about what it is exactly that your code is supposed to be doing. We have to infer the functionality from this block of code:

```
public void Start()
{
    List<Network> networks = context.Networks.ToList();

    foreach (var network in networks)
    {
        // create new client...but also
        // new client gets injected with module factory
        // module factory then populates modules based on client
        IIrcClient ircClient = this.ircClientFactory.Create();
        ircClient.Connect(network);
        this.clients.Add(ircClient);
    }
}
```

This code involves [what appears to be] private fields that you haven't included. I'll assume the following:

```
private readonly Context context;
private readonly IrcClientFactory factory;
```

If I read this correctly, your `Bot` class is depending on *concrete types*; they should be *abstractions*, like `IContext` and `IIrcClientFactory` (the latter being an *abstract factory*).

> #### Naming - Private Fields
>
> This might be of personal preference, but I like my private fields prefixed with an underscore. Having `_context` and `_factory` removes the ambiguity in the constructor and then the `this` qualifier becomes redundant:
>
> ```
> public Bot(Context context, IrcClientFactory factory)
> {
>     _factory = factory
>     _context = context
> }
> ```

The comment `// injected factory` is a useless one; prefer XML comments for that purpose:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Creates a new instance of a Bot.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="context">The data context.</param>
 /// <param name="factory">A factory that creates IrcClient instances.</param>
 public Bot(Context context, IrcClientFactory factory)
 {
     _factory = factory
     _context = context
 }
```

As a bonus, you'll get instant IntelliSense support for your constructor and its parameters.

Back to the `foreach` loop; the code you have here doesn't seem to be using the fields you've initialized in your constructor:

> ```
> IIrcClient ircClient = this.ircClientFactory.Create();
> ```

I would have expected:

```
IIrcClient ircClient = this.factory.Create();
```

I would rewrite it like this:

```
var client = _factory.Create();
```

> #### Implicit Typing
>
> The *abstract factory* shouldn't be revealing the implementation of its *product* to its client; the factory's `Create()` method should be returning an implementation for `IClient`, and shouldn't have to even know what possible implementations the factory can spit out. Your code is expecting an `IIrcClient` which is an abstraction, but from the rest of your code I infer that `IIrcClient` extends the `IClient` interface. Bottom line, the code doesn't care what type is returned, and it should be working against all implementations of `IClient` (assuming `Connect(Network)` is a member of `IClient`).
>
> Implicit typing not only makes your code shorter and easier to read, it also emphasize that you don't really care what the actual type is.

After creating a `client`, the loop's body passes the `network` to the client through its `Connect` method, and then the `client` gets added to yet another unmentioned field, assuming:

```
private readonly _clients = new List<IClient>();`
```

```
public void Start()
{
    var networks = context.Networks.ToList();
    foreach (var network in networks)
    {
        var client = _factory.Create();
        client.Connect(network);
        _clients.Add(client);
    }
}
```

If the `network` parameter is passed into a field of the `client`, and used anywhere other than in the `Connect` method, it would probably be best to constructor-inject the `network` into the `client` inside the factory method. If it's passed into a field of the `client` but isn't used anywhere other than the `Connect` method, it would be best to constructor-inject the `network` into the `client` inside the factory method; what I'm trying to get to, is that constructor injection should always be prioritized over other forms of injections, whenever possible. In this case, I'd probably call the `IClient` implementation something like `ConnectedClient` and inject the `network` through the `Create` method, which returns an `IClient` with a connection, as the `ConnectedClient` implementing class' name says.

---

Reviewing the rest of this code is very hard, I'm not seeing all the pieces of the puzzle that I'd like to see in order to be confident in anything else I'd have to say.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, to be truthful I've been very busy with other work related things but eventually I'll come round to this since I asked this some time ago. I do appreciate this so give me some time :)

Comment: I recall i ended up changing my complete architecture so that its based on a request / response pattern rather than associating and injecting dependencies like i am (from my sketchy memory)